# Como instalar plugins em contas separadas?

Tags: wordpress

Tenho:

- um servidor FTP com CPanel a correr sobre WHMCS
- três bases de dados MySQL ligadas a utilizadores diferentes
- três contas de WordPress associadas às bases de dados atrás assinaladas

Como instalar um *plugin* separadamente, e ligar a instalação deste mesmo *plugin* às três contas de WordPress?

Pretendo fazer isto porque vou ter pela frente um projecto de grandes dimensões, e preciso de poder actualizar **numa só localização o *plugin***, que pretendo ligar com as várias contas, de modo **a facilitar, a nível de arquitectura, a actualização do mesmo**

Alguém forneceu-me esta solução no Stack Overflow em inglês. contudo, preciso de saber se isto move os ficheiros originais apagando-os, e se sim, qual o comando para copiar os ficheiros, de forma não destrutiva

```
// Set WP_CONTENT_DIR to the full local path of this directory (no trailing slash), e.g.
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-content' );
// Set WP_CONTENT_URL to the full URI of this directory (no trailing slash), e.g.
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example/blog/wp-content');
// Set WP_PLUGIN_DIR to the full local path of this directory (no trailing slash), e.g.
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-content/plugins' );
// Set WP_PLUGIN_URL to the full URI of this directory (no trailing slash), e.g.
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL', 'http://example/blog/wp-content/plugins');
// If you have compability issues with plugins Set PLUGINDIR to the full local path of this directory (no trailing slash), e.g.
define( 'PLUGINDIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-content/plugins' );
```

Comment: Não seria melhor montar os três em um ambiente mulsite? assim um plugin ativado na rede fica disponível para todos, e os usuários recebem acesso aos sites que vc determina. veja [aqui](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) como proceder

Comment: eu conheço o multisite. a questão é que o obJectivo é fazer milhares de threads para tipos diferentes de site. e não se pretende que fiquem numa só instalação, por outras questões relacionadas com arquitectura de sistema.

Comment: de qualquer das formas mesmo que um network, vou ter de criar múltiplas iterações do meu proJecto, de modo que criar uma só instalação não resolve o problema das actualizações do plugin, que tem de ser feitas a partir de uma só localização. mesmo assim obrigado :)

Comment: Oi, Tiago, não precisa marcar sua edição no texto, cada post tem um histórico que dá pra conferir quem editou o quê. Adicionei marcadores de comentário no seu código pra facilitar a leitura, normalmente ninguém edita código numa pergunta, mas como o problema não é esse, achei que facilitava a leitura.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma técnica é modificar condicionalmente constantes no `wp-config.php`. Dá pra ter uma única base de arquivos do WordPress com um único `wp-config.php` e servir vários domínios, cada um com seu banco de dados separado.

```
define( 'DB_USER', 'user' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'pass' );
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );

if ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='www.example.com' ) {
    define( 'DB_NAME', 'www_db' );
    define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/com.example/wp-content/www' );
    define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://www.example.com/wp-content/www');
} 
elseif ( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='sub.example.com' ) {
    define( 'DB_NAME', 'sub_db' );
    define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/com.example/wp-content/sub' );
    define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example.com/wp-content/sub');
}

define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR', '/com.example/wp-content/plugins' );
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL', 'http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins');
define( 'WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR', '/com.example/wp-content/mu-plugins' );
define( 'WPMU_PLUGIN_URL', 'http://www.example.com/wp-content/mu-plugins');
```

[Esta pesquisa no WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=wp-config%20is%3Aq) é um bom lugar para começar a investigar o tema.

---

Outra opção é usar o [WordPress Multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network). O princípio é o mesmo, uma instalação, vários sites, mas ao converter um site normal em Multisite, um painel de super-admin aparece e dali é possível criar sub-sites e controlar quais temas e plugins podem usar. Nativamente, só é possível controlar os temas disponíveis para cada site, mas é possível fazer um plugin para deixar [plugins exclusivos para alguns dos sub-sites](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53866/how-to-use-a-must-use-plugin-to-hide-a-regular-one-and-to-hide-itself/53867#53867). Nesse exemplo, o filtro importante é `all_plugins`.

Gerenciar um Multisite tem suas particularidades que adicionam outro nível de dificuldade, [nesta wiki de tag](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/multisite/info) tem alguns recursos úteis.

---

Nas duas opções, a gestão de plugins deve ser feita com muito cuidado, é fácil derrubar vários sites de uma só vez com um erro de ortografia.

Independente da configuração escolhida para instalar vários WPs, os super-gerenciadores que [cita o Felipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88127/como-instalar-plugins-em-contas-separadas/88129#88129) são bem bons. Na prática, só conheço o InfiniteWP e gosto muito, mas sei que o ManageWP é bem bom.

Comment: ok. vou experimentar o script que me indicam, Jogar um pouco com a API do wordpress, etc. basicamente, se eu modificar o wp-config para aquilo que me indicam o script vai assumir a pasta indicada no caminho, como pasta de contents, themes, etc? no fundo o que pretendo. atenciosamente, com votos de um bom outono.

Answer (score 3):

Encontro duas maneiras para realizar isso. A primeira delas é automatizando a atualização de `plugins` quando tiver atualizações disponíveis. A configuração é realizada via `filter`, e pode inclusive limitar-se apenas a alguns `plugins`:

```
function auto_update_specific_plugins ( $update, $item ) {
    // Array of plugin slugs to always auto-update
    $plugins = array ( 
        'akismet',
        'buddypress',
    );
    if ( in_array( $item->slug, $plugins ) ) {
        return true; // Always update plugins in this array
    } else {
        return $update; // Else, use the normal API response to decide whether to update or not
    }
}
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', 'auto_update_specific_plugins', 10, 2 );
```

[Aqui temos a documentação do Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates), que contém inclusive mais sugestões.

Se for necessário ter um controle da atualização, recomendo a utilização de serviços de gerenciamento (todos pagos):

- [ManageWP](http://managewp.com)
- [InfiniteWP](https://infinitewp.com/)

Ambas soluções são bem completas, e tem *features* bastante interessantes.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta. não resolve o meu problema, pelo seguinte. não pretendo ter um gestor de wordpress; o update tem de ser feito numa só instalação do plugin feita à parte, que é disponibilizada automaticamente para todas as contas do serviço. se tiver um milhão de utilizadores, não posso fazer o update nesses utilizadores todos separadamente, pois isso vai-me gerar um volume elevado de tráfego intenso. aquilo que pretendo é ter uma só instalação do plugin, e poder actualizá-la separadamente, de modo a ficar disponível a partir de uma só localização para todas as contas

Comment: Entendi. No caso a atualização não seria pelo Painel do `wordpress` e sim diretamente via FTP. Nesse caso realmente minha resposta não ajuda.

Comment: a transposição do algoritmo proposto pode ser ainda assim interessante, para automatizar o update desse plugin, caso o update seJa feito a partir de uma quarta conta de wordpress, que vai disponibilizar o plugin as três restantes, que depois vão ser replicadas em milhares de contas de wordpress, a partir de um script

Comment: @TiagoMoraisMorgado faz sentido. Vou manter a resposta pois pode servir de ajuda caso alguém venha a pesquisar sobre o assunto. Mas vou pesquisar sobre esse seu modelo.

Comment: muito obrigado por se colocar na pele de outros utilizadores. é sempre bom ver pessoas cordeais e generosas, com o seu tipo de atitude. capazes a repensarem a solução de um problema desta natureza, mantendo ao mesmo tempo um interesse pela salvaguarda de outros utilizadores. continuação de um bom dia. votos de uma excelente semana

Comment: Felipe, ficou parecendo que sugere colocar aquele código no `wp-config.php`...

Comment: Tem razão, na verdade pode até causar conflitos. Era pra ter mostrado o exemplo no `wp-config` e através do `filter`. Edito assim que possível.